# LEFT JOIN Clause

Tags: database-design, join, select, sqlite

I think it would be better for me to just ask why it is that we use the `LEFT JOIN` clause for the following task?

> List all manufacturer name and phone number that have poor sales… less than 3 sales of any model they make.  Note, some manufacturers may not have any sales!  They should be included!

The following are our tables:

#### Orders

- Order number (Primary Key)
- Date of order
- Customer ID (Primary Key for Customers table)
- Serial Number (Primary Key for Machines table)

#### Customers

- ID (Primary Key)
- Name
- Phone Number
- Street (ie. 505 Ramapo Valley Road)
- City (ie. Mahwah)
- State
- Zip

#### Machines

- Serial Number (Primary Key)
- Model Number (Primary Key for Models table)
- Model
- ID (Primary key)
- Speed
- RAM
- HD
- Price
- Manufacturer ID (Primary key for Manufacturer table)

#### Manufacturer

- ID (Primary Key)
- Name
- Phone Number
- Email Address

The following was our entire SQL statement for this problem:

```
SELECT Manufacturer.Name, Manufacturer.PhoneNo, COUNT(Orders.OrderNo) as NoOfOrders
FROM Manufacturer
LEFT JOIN Model 
    ON Manufacturer.ID = Model.ManufacturerID
LEFT JOIN Machines 
    ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNo
LEFT JOIN Orders 
    ON Machines.SerialNo = Orders.SerialNo
GROUP BY Orders.OrderNo
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` doesn't *exclude* anything by nature, rather it *includes* all **rows** from the table on the left side of the `JOIN` clause and it will also include all matching rows from the table in the right hand side (all columns included from both tables based on what you specify in your `SELECT` list, in this case you used `*` which means all columns). For any rows in the left hand side that don't have a match in the right hand side, the values of the columns for the right hand table will be `NULL` values.

Please see the [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-join/) section of this article for a data visual and good explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN does **not** include or exclude something into output columns list. It only defines how the rows from left table and from right table are related and must be combined.

In your particular code

```
SELECT * 
FROM Manufacturer 
LEFT JOIN Model ON Model.ManufacturerID = Manufacturer.ID;
```

`LEFT JOIN` defines that for each separate row from `Manufacturer` table - if exists at least one row in `Model` table which' `ManufacturerID` value is equal to `Manufacturer.ID` value then each matching row from `Model` is attached to this row from `Manufacturer` table. As a result - the number of combined rows for **this** row from `Manufacturer` table will be equal the amount of matched rows from `Model` table. If none row in `Model` table matches the row from `Manufacturer` table then one final row is formed, and the pseudo-row with NULL value in all columns will be created and attached instead of real row from `Model` table.

`SELECT *` defines that the values from all columns from both `Manufacturer` table and `Model` table must be included into the output data. It is here that it is defined that *attributes ID, Speed, RAM, HD, and Price from the Model's table* are selected.

Comment: In other words, if there is an ID from the Manufacturer's table (left table in this case) that does not link with a ManufacturerID from the Model's table (right table in this case), then the table will show the ID from the Manufacturer's table, but will display NULL for the Model's table for Model.ID in that particular row?

Comment: @DonaldAlesson *but will display NULL for the Model's table for Model.ID in that particular row?* Not only for `Model.ID` but for all columns taken from `Model` table.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I gathered that Manufacturers, which **must** have Machines, which **must** be of certain Models, which Serial Numbers **may or may not** have been used in Orders from Customers, must be returned in association with said Orders amounts.

Based on that, what you need are **INNER JOIN**s between Manufacturers, Machines and Models - which *guarantees* these relationships exist - being **LEFT OUTER JOIN**ed to Orders, which will include them *if they exist*. So it would look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT Manufacturer.Name, Manufacturer.PhoneNo, COUNT(Orders.OrderNo) AS NoOfOrders
    FROM Manufacturer
    INNER JOIN Machines ON Manufacturer.ID = Machines.ManufacturerID
    INNER JOIN Model ON Machines.ModelNo = Model.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON Machines.SerialNo = Orders.SerialNo
GROUP BY Manufacturer.Name, Manufacturer.PhoneNo
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderNo) < 3
ORDER BY NoOfOrders, Manufacturer.Name
```